# Detect Cancel Button Tap for "Confirm Your In-App Purchase" UIAlert

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, in-app-purchase, storekit

I implemented in-app purchase based on [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2797/introduction-to-in-app-purchases) tutorial. The problem I experience is that I cannot detect when Cancel button is pressed on the *"Confirm Your In-App Purchase"* alert, which is a part of StoreKit framework.

Some sources suggest `-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions` is called when Cancel is pressed but in my case it never runs. My set up is the ViewController which imports IAPManager:NSObject class which conforms to SKProductRequestDelegate and SKPaymentTransactionObserver. Product is successfully being requested but transaction observer is never calling `paymentQueue`.

How can I make it work so I can detect Cancel button?

Answer (score 13):

in delegate method i look at the tutorial failedtransaction does nothing if user cancels. but you can add it like that.

```
- (void)failedTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled)
    {
        // error!
          NSLog(@"Something went Wrong!");
        [self finishTransaction:transaction wasSuccessful:NO];
          NSLog(@"transaction error :%@", transaction.error.localizedDescription);
    }
    else
    {
          NSLog(@"Cancelled");
        // this is fine, the user just cancelled
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This line had to be added to make it work:

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
```

Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used StoreKit, but I'm guessing that your `SKRequestDelegate` will receive the message [`request:didFailWithError:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKRequestDelegate/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/SKRequestDelegate/request%3adidFailWithError%3a) if the user cancels.

Comment: No, that method is not being called too.

Comment: Hmm. You're sure that you're setting your view controller as the delegate?

Comment: My ViewController imports IAPManager (NSObject) which sets SKRequestDelegate and other delegates (SKProductRequestDelegate and SKPaymentTransactionObserver).